# Python - For loop If statment not evaluating

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying to create a new column in the dataframe that will have the following logic:

If column A is greater than zero, then use column A. Otherwise, use column B. When I run the function, it only looks like the else clause is true. However, there are values clearly greater than zero in column A. I feel like there is something basic that I am missing here, but my internet searches have not turned up anything fruitful or my nascent python skill is not making it obvious to me.

```
def master_value():
  for i, row in data_all.iterrows():     
    if data_all[row['column A']] > 0: 
        data_all[row['New Column']] = data_all[row['Column A']]
    else:
        data_all[row['New Column']] = data_all[row['Column B']]
return data_all
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are sure the data in column a is an integer?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you please give us an example of the input and expected output?

Comment: `column A` and `Column A` are two different strings.

Comment: First, I had heard this was a great community of developers, but I am really impressed by the response in less than 24 hours. Thank you and I am looking forward to giving back once I learn more. 

@23k - yes the columns are integers: Here is the info() output:
cust_id             9175 non-null int64
column A         8310 non-null float64
column B       974 non-null float64

to Ken - sorry I forgot that Python cares about capitalization. In my code the columns are correctly capitalized, but thank you for pointing that out as watch-out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating through rows will work, though it is far faster to use [numpy.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
data_all['New Column'] = np.where(data_all['Column A'] > 0, data_all['Column A'], data_all['Column B'])
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

If you have the time - I would love to know why you think my original code failed. Thanks!

Comment: I think that in your loop's first if statement, the `row['column A']` is an integer, and pandas doesn't know what to do with an integer in the brackets `data_all[0]`. It is looking for a column name.